# How to get data from JMeter to influxDB with backend listener?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, influxdb, grafana

I'm working with JMeter 2.13 and influxDB 0.8.8 and trying to get JMeter data to influxDB by using backend listener.

First of all i installed influxDB, changed its configuration for JMeter and run it successfully. Also i added new databases and post some data to it.

*my influxDB configuration*
[image]

i added databases and one of them name is jmeter. It should hold JMeter result data
[image]

Finally i create thread group in JMeter. That gorup has one sampler with name TNX01 and backend listener with below properties.
[image]

When i run JMeter i expect that JMeter sends data to influxDB by backend listener and i can see them in influxDB ui; however, nothing happened..

What did i miss, that JMeter result are not seen at influxDB? Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the influxdb.conf file. Find the graphite section and uncomment the following lines and add the database line. It works for influxdb 0.9.3

```
[[graphite]]
   enabled = true
   bind-address = ":2003"
   protocol = "tcp"
   database = "jmeter"
   consistency-level = "one"
   name-separator = "."
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the config file as given below

[image]

Make sure that influxdb reads the config file you updated.

I am able to send the data using backend listener to **influxdb** & use **grafana** for charts.

More details can be found here.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-real-time-results-influxdb-grafana/